# Mysql and MySQL56 not working together since windows 10 update

Tags: mysql

Since my Windows 10 update, when I start mysql56 I get the following error:

[image: Error mysql]

When I then try to stop and start mysql first I get the following error:

[image: Error mysql56]

Why can't I run both together?

Comment: What ports are each of these services running on? If it's the same port, that could be your issue.

Comment: You are probably right I tried rebooting the computer and turning on and off the services several times and all of a sudden it worked.